# liberty 8554 does not refresh xhtml files

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am playing with liberty profile 8.5.5.4 in eclipse. I have the "automatically publish  when resource changes" checked. I still have to restart the service when I make changes to xhtml jsf files. Is there a workaround? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

setting the javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE to Development in web.xml worked! It now refreshes the server on xhtml file change.